# mySQL "greatest" with two columns that can be null

Tags: mysql

Why does `GREATEST(createdTS, modifiedTS)` with one of each column "null" return "null"?

If one of both is null, I simply need the value of the other. If both are null, then null.

How can I do that?

As I noticed I can use `COALESCE` like `GREATEST(COALESCE(createdTS,0), COALESCE(modifiedTS,0))` - is that the best solution?

Comment: Try using Greatest(NVL(createdTS, 0), NVL(modifiedTS_0)). Logical operations on NULL result in NULL.

Comment: Just found out that  GREATEST(COALESCE(createdTS,0), COALESCE(modifiedTS,0)) does work - is that better? Or is yours preferred?

Comment: In this case, I see no reason for using Coalesce instead of NVL. Coalesce is intended when you have expressions with multiple values, here your columns are single values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's how `null` is, so you may do it using `ifnull`.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

You may do something like this:

```
mysql> select GREATEST(ifnull(1234,0),ifnull(null,0)) as g;
+------+
| g    |
+------+
| 1234 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you are doing the comparison for non fractional data, you can do it as above.

You can also use the `COALESCE` function for that.

Comment: It works for me with date type : select *, greatest(ifnull(dateA,'1970-01-01') , ifnull(dateB,'1970-01-01') ) as dateMax

Answer (score 1):

Before MySQL 5.0.13, GREATEST() returns NULL only if all arguments are NULL. As of 5.0.13, it returns NULL if any argument is NULL.

Comment: tbh, what a stupid decision. How is NULL ever a greater date than an actual date.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest

Comment: It's not about being greater or not. It's about the meaning of "NULL". If null is "unknown", performing any logical operation, such as great, equals, etc with "unknown" - how can I know if A > NULL if I cannot say a thing about NULL ? The operation then results NULL. Seems logic.

Comment: NULL is a tricky concept, I remember having a hard time grasping why in the world do we need to represent "something I do not know about" if I do not know about in the first place! :-) What helped me was understanding that in DataBase contexts, in a RDBMS, for instance, if a new record is added, and all the non required fields are not provided, then it would be wrong to store the record values for those fields as their "default/initials" values, since this is not what the user did. Instead, we need a way to represent the absence of a value. Then NULL comes into place.

Comment: Got you @Veverke. If asking a human "which date is bigger, 04/22/15 or unknown", he probably would reply "I can't know this" - so, NULL is correct in that case...

Comment: It's about how the language was designed to work. Once you can have scenarios - totally legitimate - like the one I describe above - how should the language proceed? If a field was left untouched and therefore has no real data whatsoever - if I ask the DB to retrieve the greatest value between 10 and this "undefined" value, what should the DB return ? Returning 10 would be incorrect, because the field was never added a value to start with (it's not zero, which would be the case did the user wish to when adding the record to the table). Returning NULL, rather, is the only meaningful thing to do

Comment: So you can know that you are dealing with a field with no value whatsoever. If you got 10 you would assume the field has a value, which is does not.

Comment: @RaphaelJeger the only problem I have with that is the fact MIN() and MAX() are not consistent with this. Given 123 and NULL, both will return 123 and return NULL only if all values are NULL.